# elasticsearch комментарии к полям индекса

Tags: elasticsearch

Перехожу с MySQL на Elasticsearch. В таблицах есть комментарии пример:

```
statusOfVerification     tinyint          default 0                     not null comment 'Пройден модерацию 1 - пройден, 2 временно не показывается по требованию администратора',
```

как перенести эти комментарии в _mapping индекса Elasticsearch 7.8, чтобы не потерять сакральную информацию о значениях столбцов ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

наткнулся на [обсуждения 2015 года](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9649) в них рассматривается вопрос о принятии комментариев в _mapping индекса. Предложение было отвергнуто с отсылкой использовать поле `_meta` туда можно писать комментарии

[документация](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/mapping-meta-field.html)